# force dnsmasq to bind an interface for DHCP

Tags: dhcp, socket, interface, dnsmasq

I want to use dnsmasq with two configs on two interfaces, which should be bound locally. If you read the manpage, it looks like `interface=wlan0` `bind-interfaces` should do the trick. But it always binds the dhcp server to all interfaces:

```
udp        0      0 192.168.101.1:53        0.0.0.0:*                           0          7410711     22333/dnsmasq   
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:67              0.0.0.0:*                           0          7410708     22333/dnsmasq
```

Config:

```
interface=wlan0
except-interface=lo
except-interface=wlan0_0
no-dhcp-interface=wlan0_0
dhcp-range=interface:wlan0,192.168.101.2,192.168.101.255,60m
bind-interfaces
```

Commandline: `dnsmasq -C /etc/dnsmasq.wlan0.conf -z`

Many of the options should be redundant in theory, but in practice it still binds to `0.0.0.0:67`.

Comment: Why do you think you need to run two instances of dnsmasq?  It is perfectly valid to have two ranges in a instance.

Comment: BTW, I am not sure looking at the output of netstat/ss would be meaningful here.  Remember this is DHCP, it happens when a client doesn't have an IP address, it almost certainly can't bind to a specific address.  I am not sure  how dnsmasq supposedly works with multiple DHCP instances.  It must be doing something unusual.

Comment: I want two nets, with dnsmasq-instances, which behave different on name resolution (one should only resolve local dns-names, one should forward to an upstream dns), there running two instances seems the easiest way. DHCP should be nothing but udp, so there should be no problem binding the socket to an interface. (or an interface ip). That it's actually binding is the problem, as the second instance tells me "cannot bind", so there are no raw sockets or similiar involved.

Answer (score 1):

You can do everything you want with one instance.  This is an example based on a configuration I have used.

```
# DHPC ranges set tag
dhcp-range=set:able,192.168.20.10,192.168.20.100,255.255.255.0,48h
dhcp-range=set:baker,192.168.30.10,192.168.30.100,255.255.255.0,192h

# Tag dependent options
dhcp-option=able,3,192.168.20.1           # Router
dhcp-option=able,15,able.example.com      # Domain
dhcp-option=baker,3,192.168.20.1          # Router
dhcp-option=baker,15,baker.example.com    # Domain

# Common settings
dhcp-option=6,192.168.20.2,192.168.30.2   # DNS servers
dhcp-option=19,0                          # Option ip-forwarding off
dhcp-option=20,0                          # Source routing off
dhcp-option=27,1                          # All sub-nets are local
dhcp-option=31,0                          # Router Discovery off
dhcp-option-force=42,192.168.20.5         # NTP time servers
dhcp-option=119,able.example.com,example.com # Search List
```

This is covered in the man page.

Comment: Hmm, i will look into it, maybe i can build a solution with a unified config. But that's no solution to the problem in the question, which would allows for dynamically launching dhcp-server instances on new interfaces.

Comment: can you use ``address=`` with such tags? That was the problem, i wanted one net to resolve hosts addresses to a gateway-page with ``address=`` wildcard. And this option does not support such tags (according to the manpage)

Comment: @allo  I think you are looking for a captive portal type solution.

Comment: Indeed, but i do not need or want a full captive portal. What i want is: 1) two (B)SSIDS 2) use two IP ranges 3) provide different DNS to them using dnsmasq. 3a) push addresses for something similiar to a captive portal 3b) normal dns name resolution. 1, 2 are working with one instance, for 3 the most elegant solution seems to be having two dnsmasq instances one with address= and one without. The problem is 2 times dnsmasq does not work as long as it binds all interfaces for dhcp, one config does not work as long as address= lines are global.

Comment: I think i try pushing an upstream dns to the interface which should provide global resolution, but it's not a clean solution to the problem.